# Play Video from internal Storage using Default Player

Tags: android, android-intent, video

Open Video from Internal Storage using default player

```
File newVideoPath= Environment.getDataDirectory();;
System.out.println("--------------->"+newVideoPath.getPath());
Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse(newVideoPath.getParent()+"/myvid.mp4"));
intent.setDataAndType(Uri.parse(newVideoPath.getPath()+"/myvid.mp4"), "video/mp4");
startActivity(intent);
```

I copied the video to `Android/data` but MXPlayer opens and says cannot play video. What am I doing wrong?